# How can set Interface orientation to all views

Tags: ios, interface-orientation

How can implement Interface Orientation in iphone app. I want to apply interface orientation to all  view controllers.

Answer (score 2):

In your AppDelegate.m file set:

For Landscape

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

For Portrait:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

For both:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
     return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}
```

Comment: I need both portrait and landscape orientation

Comment: So what is your problem? You ask how you can set interface orientation for the app. If you want to support both, what is the issue?

Comment: Anyway, edited my answer with code to support both.